# Multiple volatile fields performance vs synchronize block in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, java-memory-model

In latest [InfoQ eMag](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/emag-java-9) i came across sentence:

> Declaring  any  field  as  “volatile”  doesn’t  mean  that  locking 
>   is  involved,  so  volatiles  are  less   expensive  than 
>   synchronizations   that  use  locks.  But  it’s  important   to  note 
>   that  having  multiple  voatile  fields  inside  your  methods
>   could  make  them  more  expen- sive than locking those methods.

What bothers me is the second part:

> But  it’s  important   to  note 
>   that  having  multiple  voatile  fields  inside  your  methods
>   could  make  them  more  expensive than locking those methods

According to [The JSR-133 cookbook](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html) Volatile load has the same **memory effect** as monitor enter so 
how the second sentence  can be true?

Comment: if you acquire a mutex, than operate several non-volatile variables under that mutex, it may *in total* be less expensive then operating these variables one-by-one if they are volatile

Comment: Every time you access a volatile member variable its value is fetched from the main memory, instead of using the cached copy in the thread context, which is likely to reside in the CPU's 1st or 2nd level cache. If you do this just often enough, the cost of the memory access outweighs the cost of the lock. Actually, accessing a volatile member might copy more than just that member's value from the main memory, making the process even more expensive.

Comment: @Ralf that's true. But there is also a cost of the variable telling the JVM that it has to do all writings before reading or is this negligible?

Comment: Although they have the same memory effect they are not implemented in the same way. What you quote is context-dependent - there are situations where it will be true and some situations where it won't (which is why they said *could*).

Comment: @ElMac, if you refer to the cost of executing the memory fence instruction, then this is the cost you incur when reading or writing from/to a volatile member. Memory fences are a feature of the underlying CPU architecture and the exact cost varies between them.

Comment: @Ralf that's true but running inside synchronized block doesn't give us the same overhead?

Comment: @user2956098 Yes, and more. Object monitors cause other threads to wait, you may have contention on the lock, etc. So normally a synchronized block would be more expensive than using volatile members. But with the monitor in place you only need to read the state of the locked object once from the main memory, then write it back before exiting from the synchronized block. No matter how often you read or write the state of the synchronized object inside the synchronized block. If you read/write a lot from/to volatile members, you are reaching out to the main memory all the time.

Comment: Of course the synchronized block is more expensive. But you don't have the same functionality inside a volatile field. You can't make a group of dependant changes. If you are going to write only to one field, then you can do it volatile (or use an atomic object). If you need to write atomically to more than one object, you will need to synchronize.

Comment: @Ralf it's clear for me now, thanks. Unfortunately it is impossible to mark comment as a accepted answer.

Comment: @ElMac, you are right, of course, but that was not the question. The question was only about the cost of volatile vs. synchronized given the fact that their memory effect is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing a volatile field has three effects:

1. The VM requires the program to respect a *synchronization order* (not the same as the `synchronized` keyword) for surrounding variables.
2. The thread accessing the volatile field needs to synchronize its caches with other threads accessing this volatile field.
3. Accessing a variable access must be atomic for `long` and `double` types (on 64-bit architectures, this is happening anyways).

Entering / leaving a `synchronized` block only has effects (1) and (2) whereas atomic access is implicit if a `long` or `double` field is only accessed within such a block.  Additionally, of course, synchronized blocks imply locking a monitor.

I [have given talks on the details of these effects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgiXKPEILoc) on numerous occasions if you want to learn more about it. It is too complex to cover it fully on Stack Overflow.

In practice, these requirements are overfullfilled by most VMs. For example, the HotSpot VM comes close to the suggestion of the JMM-cookbook and issues memory barriers after accessing volatile variables. Similar memory barriers are added before and after adding a `synchronized` block.

The above statememt can therefore become true if **the overhead of accessing *N* volatile fields** outweights **the overhead of two such memory barriers plus aquiring the mutex** where one accesses *N* volatile fields from within the mutex. I doubt that one can make a meaningful statement for how many variables one would need to access before a single synchronized block becomes more efficient. The VM is pretty smart with optimizations and can for example bulk memory refreshings or it can on the other side erase the aquiration of a mutex. I would always try to express what is more semantically correct; code against the specification, not the implementation. If you do the latter, be sure to properly benchmark your results and even before that, make sure you actually need to squeeze out that little bit of performance.

Answer (score -1):

Well as I understand, a volatile field acts in the same way as it would act if it was locked. In *most* JVM implemenations, it won't use a lock (although it may).

<del>As far as I know, the volatile keyword does not guarantee atomic operations.</del> All volatile operations (including double and long) are guaranteed to be atomic. You might have a missing-update problem here (because it does not actually synchronize / block). If you want atomic operations use the Atomic classes or synchronize it yourself.

I don't know the exact definition, it has also been changed in Java 5. What I say here is just a direction it might be, but don't build an application using what I said :)

**EDIT:**

Here is an important sentence from the Atomic Access [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) from Oracle.

> [...] any write to a volatile variable establishes a happens-before
>   relationship with subsequent reads of that same variable.

So if you do a single synchronized block you might be faster than if you have a lot of volatile fields creating this relationship.

Comment: Please feel free to make better answers and/or edit mine. I wan't to know too :)

Comment: anyway, volatile reads and writes are atomic, so you're not exactly correct.